# Set default db in oracledb

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, codeigniter

I finished a project using codeigniter and mysql and I am now required to migrate the project so it can work with oracledb.
One problem I am facing is the default db. In mysql I can choose the default db so instead of

```
SELECT * FROM mypj.user
```

I can just do

```
SELECT * FROM user
```

In Oracle, is there anything equivalent to that feature? I tried creating synonym but some of them are already used by other people. I wrote the whole sql queries, not with activerecord so cannot use the prefix db name config.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use 3rd argument from [oci_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php) in format host/db name, check out example from php site:

```
// Connects to the XE service (i.e. database) on the "localhost" machine
$conn = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'localhost/XE');
```

Comment: I am not so clear about oracledb as this is the first time I use it. I am able to connect to the oracle db server using these arguments oci_connect('prj***', 'pass***', '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = sidt***)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = sidt)))'); Now everytime I select data from table User, I have to do :  select * from ownmpl.user. What is the ownmpl, is it the service name like XE in your example?

Comment: @navie yes, change XE to ownmpl